# Need help identifying DFN-8 Part

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, surface-mount

[image: Image of Unknown Components]

I've got an 8 pin DFN-8 package I can't seem to identify. Things I know:

1. Its a DFN-8 2mmx2mm
2. Its got a large pad underneath
3. Pins 2 and 5 are connected to the GND on the micro-usb connector on the other side of the board as well as the middle pad.
4. The resistor between pins 1 and 3 is 100kohm.
5. The resistor between pin 6 and the rest of the circuit is 100kohm.
6. Pins 4 and 7 are not connected and are floating.
7. Its marked "DAS"

Its either a gate driver, LDO, or some sort of specialized power-on controller. I think it might be made by on-semi, but I'm not able to find anything that matches.

The 6 pin component to its immediate left is a TSSOP-6 or SOT-363 with the markings "KPE". My research turns up a Toshiba P-FET SSM6J402TU.

This is out of a Sony product, and as such, everything seems to be Japanese in origin (at least company ownership).

Answer (score 3):

The markings and connections match with a [Texas Instruments BQ24308DSGR](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2303010107_Texas-Instruments-BQ24308DSGR_C2876164.pdf) Protection IC.
[image]
[image]

It's hard to tell from the blurry picture, but I think the style of the markings matches as well:
[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Battery-Management-ICs_Texas-Instruments-BQ24308DSGR_C2876164.html))