# What is this IC marked R876B?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, diodes, triac

[image]

Can everybody help me find this IC marked R876B?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide further context - such as the purpose of the board the IC is on, the IC's pinout, dimensions & periphery, etc.

Comment: Please take a look at [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/671303/need-help-identifying-dfn-8-part). This is what I would consider a good identification question. It only lacks a nice close up picture. The only thing you provide here.

Comment: HNLinh - Hi, For the future, here are the "[Component Identification Question Guidelines](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6710)". The more information you include from that list, the better your identification questions will be received by others. Although you now have an answer, missing at the moment from the question is: "*any information about the surrounding circuit, or any knowledge on the type of system your component came from*", "*Show a schematic if you have it, or a tracing of the PCB traces if possible*" and a wider angle photo showing a larger area of the board. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [Vishay SIR876BDP](https://www.vishay.com/docs/63032/sir876bdp.pdf) N-channel MOSFET. The datasheet doesn't give any information about markings, but [LCSC](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/MOSFETs_Vishay-Intertech-SIR876ADP-T1-GE3_C114889.html) has a picture of the similar SIR876A that shows the marking style matches:

[image]